# How to change the size of font appearing on the installer window in nsis ?

Tags: nsis

I have developed my own language file for HINDI language and it's working fine. I have created two files in NSIS Contrib folder one is .nsh and second is .nlf. And its font size is default. But when I use my own language in installer, the font size of my language looks relatively small to the english languge. see below how it looks like-

[image]

In above image the second language font looks small relative to english and it's hard to read. Similar things happen on other pages like below-

[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to increase this font size of my own language. where can I do this setting or what setting should I do in my language file so that the font size will look big??

Answer (score 1):

Near the top of the .nlf file there should be a section that looks something like this:

```
# Font and size - dash (-) means default
-
-
```

You can replace the first line with a font name if you want to force a specific font and the second line is the font size.

For example, the Japanese .nlf looks like this:

```
# Font and size - dash (-) means default
ＭＳ Ｐゴシック
9
```

but it would also be legal to leave the name as `-` and just set the size.